# Hide part of email address in php

Tags: php, email

I'm having trouble.. 
I want to hide the email address like in the following example : 
instead of this email address: `testemail@gmail.com`
I want this `te********@g***.com`
I've already tried this function and it didn't work !!

> $newemail = preg_replace('/(?<=.).(?=.*@)/u','*',testemail@gmail.com);

it hides the domain of the email not the whole one !
if you guys have a better one that will be cool because I've searched over and over and I didn't see any topic that solves this problem.

Comment: *email* and *email address* are not synonyms

Comment: maybe something like [reCAPTCHA Mailhide](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#mailhide)?

Comment: please give me a solution do not suggest me.

Comment: [Your regex is simply incorrect. That's why the result comes out wrong. Fix it.](http://regex101.com/r/wS4aY8/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's learn regex!

OK, so our requirement:

> Convert characters here in bold into *s through regex:
>
> te **stemail** @ g **mail** .com

Break down:

> 1. Convert characters between 2 characters and an @ into `*`.
> 2. Convert characters between @, then a character and before ".com" into `*`.

In other words:

> Match characters between 2 characters and an @
>
> Or characters between @ + a character, and ".com"
>
> Replace with "`*`".

Proper regex would be:

```
(?<=.).(?=.*?@)|(?<=@.).*(?=\.com)
```

So replace your code with

```
$newemail = preg_replace('/(?<=.).(?=.*?@)|(?<=@.).*(?=\.com)/u', '', 'testemail@gmail.com');
```

View a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/wS4aY8/2).

**Optimization:** [The following regex](http://regex101.com/r/wS4aY8/3) works the same, but runs faster.

```
(?<=.).(?=[^@]+@)|(?<=@.).*(?=\.com)
```

Comment: +1 great informative answer, mine did the job quickly enough with an alternate solution but yours goes to the root of the problem and fixes the regex, which is more than I could do!

Comment: Thanks man , just made my day :D 
Worked as charm !!!!

Comment: @user3781028 I hope this doesn't turn out too rude, but reducing the noise in questions such as "I have annoying problem" "help pls!!!" can help us get to your question and solve it quickly. :)

Comment: @Dagon [Yes, I run my code online on "compile and run (language) online"](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php) before posting them onto SO. It doesn't generate a link to the demo as a doodle though, so I can't post something based on it.

Comment: well it still has a syntax error

Comment: @Dagon I fixed it in the latest revision. I fixed it in my test code, the email address was not wrapped in quotes. I didn't fix it when I post it, which was an oversight. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok using something other than regex:

```
$email = explode('@', "testemail@gmail.com");
$first_part = $email[0];
$domain = $email[1];

$newemail = substr($first_part, 0, 2) . "********@" . substr($domain, 0, 1) . "***." . end(explode('.', $domain));
```

It's a bit of work though, does a few things to the email address and puts it back together in a format similar to what you described.